# Get element of Array after last split in GO

Tags: arrays, go, split

I don't know if the title is clearly, i will explain my problem,

I have this piece of code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "test-email-test@gmail.com"
    fields := []string{}

    last := 0
    for i, r := range s {
        if r == '_' || r == '-' {
            fmt.Printf("%q\n", fields)
            fields = append(fields, s[last:i+1])

            last = i + 1

        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", fields)


}
```

This code prints this :

```
["test-" "email-"]
```

But i don't know how can I put in the same time the last word, "test" in the same array, so that it gives :

```
["test-" "email-" "test"]
```

Anyone has idea please ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what the end goal is, but if it is to get a list of fields separated by `-` or `_` in the username part of an email address, you may want to just use [strings.Split](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split) and [strings.FieldsFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#FieldsFunc).

You can just `Split` on `@` to get the username part, then use `FieldsFunc` to get the fields.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "aaa-bbb-ccc@yyy.zzz"
    user := strings.Split(s, "@")[0] // get the username part
    fields := strings.FieldsFunc(user, func(c rune) bool {
        return c == '-' || c == '_'
    })
    fmt.Println(fields)
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/P8nB4zqACmD)

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria to cut a string is to find a certain char. The last piece does not match this rule except if you use a string like “a-b-c-“

Advice: check if there is something after last and append it after the for-loop

Answer (score 0):

your loop will run correctly if there is "-" before the "@"
for alternative you may use

```
s := string("test-email-test@gmail.com")

fields := []string{}

name := strings.Split(s, "@") //separate from the "@"

name2 := strings.Split(name[0], "-") //separate from the "-"

for i := 0; i < len(name2); i++ {
    fields = append(fields, name2[i])
}

fmt.Println(fields)
```

output

```
[test email test]
```